# How to prevent Gstream get_buffer() from stuck when rtsp is disconnected?

Tags: python, gstreamer

I have a problem with Gstream in Python, I try to make a POC of RTSP listener.
I try to protect my code. I have problem now like a wall :D I can't break it.
When I use get_buffer() and the RTSP is not available, program stuck there.
Is there any solution to set timeout? Or other way to prevent from stuck?
I need to reconnect RTSP when disconnected, but get_buffer() stuck the program.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GLib
from urllib.parse import quote
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import time

Gst.init(None)


passs = quote('asdA@Da32')
pipelines = []


rtsp_urls = [
    f"rtsp://admin:{passs}@172.16.40.216:7001/21eaf170-115c-f23a-cc1a-0b12e82636dd",
    f"rtsp://admin:{passs}@172.16.40.216:7001/21eaf170-115c-f24a-cc1a-0b12e82636dd",
    f"rtsp://admin:{passs}@172.16.40.216:7001/21eaf170-115c-f25a-cc1a-0b12e82636dd",
    f"rtsp://admin:{passs}@172.16.40.216:7001/21eaf170-115c-f26a-cc1a-0b12e82636dd",
]


def retry():
    global pipelines
    for url in rtsp_urls:
        pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(f'rtspsrc location={url} ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! appsink name=sink{len(pipelines)}')
        appsink = pipeline.get_by_name(f'sink{len(pipelines)}')
        appsink.set_property('sync', False)
        appsink.set_property('max-buffers', 1)
        appsink.set_property('drop', True)
        pipelines.append(pipeline)
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

def rec():
    global pipelines
    print("rec")
    for pipeline in pipelines:
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    pipelines.clear()
    retry()

retry()
while True:
    try:
        for i, url in enumerate(rtsp_urls):
            start = time.time()
            try:
                pipeline = pipelines[i]
                result, state, pending = pipeline.get_state(0)
                print(result)
                print(state)
                sample = pipeline.get_by_name(f"sink{i}").emit("pull-sample")
                buffer = sample.get_buffer()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                rec()
                #retry()
            if buffer:
                try:
                    caps = sample.get_caps()
                    height = caps.get_structure(0).get_int('height')[1]
                    width = caps.get_structure(0).get_int('width')[1]
                    data = buffer.extract_dup(0, buffer.get_size())
                    image = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
                    print(time.time()-start)
                    image.save(f"{i}zdjecie.jpg", "JPEG")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            else:
                rec()
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve that by setting `reconnect` to `True`. You will have to create a `source` first and then set the `property` accordingly.

```
source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtspsrc", "rtsp-source")
source.set_property("reconnect", True)
```

You might run into other issues like https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/inference-on-rtsp-stream/112296 so watchout.